# Hodge-Tate weights of etale cohomology groups

Tags: etale-cohomology, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Given a smooth algebraic variety $X$ over a number field $F$, its $p$-adic cohomology groups $H^i(X \times_F \bar F, \mathbb Q_p)$ carries an action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar F/F)$, which gives a continuous representation $\rho: \mathrm{Gal}(\bar F/F) \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ for some $n$. For any $F$-place $v|p$ and an embedding $\bar F \to \bar F_v$, $\rho$ induces a representation of $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar F_v/F_v)$ which we denote by $\rho_v$. For an embedding $\sigma: F_v \to \overline{\mathbb Q}_p$, let $\mathrm{HT}_{\sigma}(\rho_v)$ be the corresponding Hodge-Tate weights of $\rho_v$.

I wonder if there is a way to find $X$ and $i$ with prescribed Hodge-Tate weights. Are there references to look at?